# Why does hovering an element in a div affect divs siblings?

Tags: css

I supply two pictures to show what is happening.
Before hovering:

[image]

After hovering:

[image]

The xhtml-code:

```
    <body>
      <div>
         <div class="channel"><img src="./logos/svt1.png" alt="Channel logotype" /><div class="chName">SVT1</div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <div class="prog">01.20  Plus</div>
                  <div class="info">Program info here</div>
               </li>
               <!--more <li>-->
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="channel"><img src="./logos/svt2.png" alt="Channel logotype" /><div class="chName">SVT2</div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <div class="prog">01.00  Rapport</div>
                  <div class="info">Program info here</div>
               </li>
               <!--more <li>-->
            </ul>
         </div>
         <!-- and more <div> -->
      </div>
   </body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body{
position: absolute;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

li{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

li:hover .info{
    display: block;
}

li:hover{
    border: solid 1px darkgrey;
}

div{
    display: table;
}

.channel{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 0;
}

.chName{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 40%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.info{
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

So what i am wondering is why the hovering of an `<li>` affects the `<div>`s with class = channel, and how to fix this.

If more details are needed please comment.
Thanks

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/robbannn/53j38uyh/

Comment: Would you mind making a jsFiddle?

Comment: I can absolutely try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `.channel` is set to `display: inline-block;` which means vertical alignment is honoured. The default vertical alignment for inline elements is `baseline`. When you hover over the `li` you are changing `.info` to `display: block;` which means the baseline is different.

To fix this add `vertical-align: top;` to `.channel`, it'll ensure that `.channel` is always aligned to the top of the parent.

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
li:hover .info {
  display: block;
}
li:hover {
  border: solid 1px darkgrey;
}
div {
  display: table;
}
.channel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.chName {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 40%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="channel">
    <img src="./logos/svt1.png" alt="Channel logotype" />
    <div class="chName">SVT1</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="prog">01.20 Plus</div>
        <div class="info">Program info here</div>
      </li>
      <!--more <li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="channel">
    <img src="./logos/svt2.png" alt="Channel logotype" />
    <div class="chName">SVT2</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="prog">01.00 Rapport</div>
        <div class="info">Program info here</div>
      </li>
      <!--more <li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- and more <div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.